# How to do Hierarchical Clustering for large similarity matrix

Tags: machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have around 50K data sets whose value may range between 0 and 10. I want to apply the HAC to cluster these data. But to apply HAC I need to prepare a N*N similarity matrix.

For N = 50 K , this matrix would simply be too large to hold in memory , even if I use short.

Is there any way to do HAC in batches or any other method which could help me to apply HAC with 50K data points.  I plan to implement it in java.

I am also worried about total time it would take , any pointers regarding this would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply a top-down clustering approach you could easily distribute it, related article: http://scgroup.hpclab.ceid.upatras.gr/faculty/stratis/Papers/tm07book.pdf

Long story short (quote from other article): After your first node split, each node created can be shipped to a distributed process to be split again and so on... Each distributed process needs only to be aware of the subset of the dataset it is splitting. Only the parent process is aware of the full dataset.

Bottom-up approach is much harder to distribute and I won't try to suggest anything here.

But hey, you don't need to write this in Java yourself, Mahout or MLLib libraries already have it, and they support java. And hadoop

Anyway, here is your example in Java for hadoop if you want to write it yourself:
http://sujitpal.blogspot.ru/2009/09/hierarchical-agglomerative-clustering.html

Finally, a good and big work on comparison of different distributed approaches for hierarchical clustering:

```
C. F. Olson. "Parallel Algorithms for Hierarchical Clustering." Parallel Computing, 21:1313-1325, 1995, doi:10.1016/0167-8191(95)00017-I.
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Right now I am looking for a solution which can run on single machine. I have read about top-down approach but as per wiki its time complexity could be 2^N which is even worse than N^2 or N^3. And as I know Mahout doesnt support HAC.

Comment: Then use scikit-learn. 50K datapoints + HAC is fine with it, I used to cluster a set of 100K documents with it and it worked just fine for me - it took something like 5-10 minutes on ordinal Core 2 Duo PC.

Comment: You mean 100k * 100k similarity can be done in 10 minutes? You used top down or bottom up ? Which cluster linkage you chose and how much RAM you used?

Comment: @Bankelaal I ran it for about 50K-100K of records and it ran fine on ordinal Core 2 Duo CPU + 4 GB of RAM. In general I manually calculate mutual distances  between all items with my custom function (notice - it is possible to numpy.vectorize it for great performance gain), and resulting distance matrix is passed to perform HAC with the linkage method. Since distances are already counted it takes almost no time to perform HAC itself.

Comment: Thanks , One Quetsion when you say 100K documents , it means 100K*100K similarity needs to be computed (we can reduce it by not calculating diagonal and only upper half of the matrix) , So when you say you could do this with 4G machine it must be like the distance is computed on the fly am I right ?

Comment: It is 100K of terms and for each of them we calculate distance with each of other terms, so yes, it is 100K x 100K matrix (though we calc only triangle part here). And yes, distances are computed on the fly, as far as I see. At least I haven't faced any issues with RAM or whatever (I left my PC, went to grab a coffee, returned back say 10-15 mins later and the program was completed).

Comment: :) cool , But only problem I see here is that I need to specify the no. of clusters in advance. One of the reason why I used the HAC because I can cut the dandogram at required height to generate different clusters.

Comment: Well... Then keep digging. My first thought is to: 1) Obtain approximate number of clusters by Canopy Clustering and use it 2) Switch to something else, like Ward or DBScan. Though I didn't use both of them. Ward seems to do what you require but I can't say if it will work fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are various different HAC methods, but they are generally all lower bounded by O(n^2) complexity. So while 50k is still a doable number of data points, you won't be able to scale this out too far.

I dont know what code you are using, but you don't have to explicitly store the N^2 sized similarity matrix, the similarity values can be computed on the fly / as needed. [Scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering) learn will do it without explicitly forming the matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs , I have checked the JSAT. It actually calculates the similarity matrix in advance , what it does is that it doesnt calculate the diagonals and the lower part of the triangle. But still similarity matrix is required to be calculated in advance. In my case even if I follow the way JSAT does my matrix is going to be too large. Right now  I must do this on a single machine and I do have 10-15G memory available but my concern is time and space complexity will cause a problem.

Comment: Edward - I realized you are author of JSAT. So you must be sure that in your implementation you dont store similarity matrix. And I also see you have implemented both top-down and bottom-up , For 50 K data points If I have 10-15G memory can I handle 50K resources for HAC , How much time It might take to finish it ?

Comment: I made an error, the code in JSAT does do the full matrix, I must have been thinking of some code for something else. 

Scikit doesn't require it though